# Why is View Controller scrolling above UIScrollView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard

Autolayout constraints not working properly with UIScrollView, allowing me to scroll above the scrollview even though the scrollview is constrained to the Super View, not the safe area.

[Initial Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqeBY.png)
[Scroll Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkXS1.png)

I've added a scrollview to a View Controller and constrained it to each edge of the super view, not the safe area. I've disabled "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the View Controller as well as "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars" within the "Extend Edges" block in the inspector. Everything in the storyboard appears to be correct. Also once I load the View Controller, everything also appears to be correct until I scroll up. I'm sure this relates to the Status Bar because it appears to be the exact height of it but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to adjust. This issue occurs on all devices including devices without notches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ScrollView's content inset adjustment behavior needed to be adjusted using `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`